# Try to match all images that contain a specific class using preg_match_all

Tags: php

I try to match all images that contain a specific class by using the `preg_match_all` function.

This is my old code that match the all images in the content:

```
preg_match_all( '/<img[\s\r\n]+.*?>/is', $content, $matches );
```

And this is the code that I try to made to match the images that only have a specific class but I failed:

```
preg_match_all( "/(<img((?!(.*?)class=['\"](.*?)comment-media(.*?)['\"](.*?)).)*>)+/is", $content, $matches );
```

The class that I need to search for it is: `comment-media`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches every `img` tag that has not the `comment-media` class. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6iozic/1) lists this part as being "Negative Lookahead":

```
(?!(.*?)class=['\"](.*?)comment-media(.*?)['\"](.*?))
```

You'll need to **remove that negative lookahead**.

The resulting regex expression will be:

```
(<img(.*class=['\"](.*)comment-media(.*)['\"].*)*>)+
```

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/yh7dqj/1

---

## What is a negative lookahead?

A negative lookahead is used to match something not followed by something else. It always starts with `(?!`. For example, to match a string `foo` not followed by `bar`, one would use:

```
foo(?!bar)
```

To match `foobar` not followed by digits, one would use:

```
# Notice the parenthesis around the part of the negative lookahead. You'll need these to use lookaheads with regex expressions.
foobar(?!([0-9]+)).*
```

Note that the lookahead is not part of a capturing group.

More details are available [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).